# Что лучше для сочетания UI и графических сцен?

Tags: android, libgdx

в проекте нужно сочетать:

- отображение и обработку данных в табличном и списочном виде
- графические сцены (анимацию)

графику реализую через LibGDX

но в LibGDX толкового инструментария для работы с таблицами/списками не нашел, scene2d.ui больше ориентирован на небольшие данные

но если реализовывать работу с таблицами через стандартный инструментарий android'а то как сочетать ее с участком LibGDX?

вопрос:

посоветуйте, как лучше реализовать подобную задачу,
реализовать все на LibGDX или пытаться объединить LibGDX со стандартными Activity ?

Answer (score 1):

Интересно, что за проект. Какого уровня анимация?

Если это не игра, а анимация представляет просто движение некоторых компонентов, то вполне хватит стандартных инструментов для анимации Android Studio. В крайнем случае можно рисовать на канве.

Если этот проект - не игра, то я бы даже и пытаться не стал заморачиваться с libgdx. Там не то что таблицы, а просто с текстом засядите, особенно если ещё и локализация присутствует.

Насчёт сочетать стандартный инструментарий с libgdx - чудес не бывает )))

Comment: Я сейчас пишу игру найди пару и справляюсь без `libgdx`. Все и без этого получается, только блин сложно :)

Comment: Я пишу на libgdx из-за портируемости на iOs. С графикой много удобного, но и очень много костылей всякий приходится придумывать, особенно в переводом на русский.

Comment: Это точно) Кроссплатформенность это круто, но из-за неё приходится изучать либу)

Comment: @Konstantin, какие проблемы с русским? я создал свой шрифт с поддержкой кириллицы и вроде проблем не замечаю, возможно еще не столкнулся?

Comment: @Konstantin, проект игровой, с анимацие боевки аля фалаут, но при этом хотелось работать с большими (20-100 позиций) списками данных. Вроде для этого `Table` вполне подойдет (ИМХО)

Comment: Ну раз так, тогда по-любому libgdx. "создал свой шрифт с поддержкой кириллицы" - имеется в виду прямо скин для виджетов? Или просто bitmapFont? Мне просто со скинами очень не хотелось заморачиваться. Мало того, что рисовать всё надо, так ещё и в json всё описывать.

Comment: @Konstantin, полноценный skin. Кто то из наших на флэше сделал онлайн-сервис. Выбираешь локали, цвета и т.д.. Найду ссылку скину или сам поищи.

Comment: @ravend, буду очень благодарен. Со скинами это меняет дело

Comment: @Konstantin, http://kvazars.com/littera/

Comment: @ravend спасибо огромное! Надо бы про скины и про этот сервис инфу в отдельный вопрос вынести.

Comment: @Konstantin, хорошо бы эту ссылку разместить здесь http://www.libgdx.ru. Но не вижу ссылки обратной связи на сайте.